# Unable to create a empty array in Python

Tags: python, string

I 'm a beginner in python.I created a code to make a user entered string to palindrome (Or say i want to). But the main problem is that i don't know how to create an empty array of char type(ie. string). When i compile my code i get a syntax error: `File "convert to pallindrome.py", line 14, in <module>
    s1[j]=s2[y-i]`.I don't know whether it's the problem of the empty array i created.Please help me out on this.

```
s2=raw_input('Enter the s2: ')  #read the string from user
x=len(s2)
y=x-1
s1=[20]         #another array to hold the new string
j=0
if len(s2)%2==0:                        #if length of string is even
    for i in range(0,y/2-1):        #do until i<=half of string length
            if s2[i]==s2[y-i]:
                    s1[j]=s2[i]
                    j=j+1           #if characters are equal then copy the character to array
            elif s2[i]!=s2[y-i]:
                    s1[j]=s2[i]
                    j=j+1
                    s1[j]=s2[y-i]
                    j=j+1           #if characetrs are not equal then copy both the letters
    elif len(s2)%2!=0:                      #if length of string is odd
    for i in range(0,y/2-1):
            if s2[i]==s2[y-i]:
                    s1[j]=s2[i]
                    j=j+1
            elif s2[i]!=s2[y-i]:
                    s1[j]=s2[i]
                    j=j+1
                    s1[j]=s2[y-i]
                    j=j+1           #do same as above
 z=2*len(s1)             #get 2xlength of string 
 if z%2==0:
    for i in range(0,z-1):
            if i<=z/2:
                    s1[z-i]=s1[i]   #copy first half to the second half of string  to create the pallindrome.
  if z%2!=0:
    for i in range(0,z-1):
            if i<=(z/2)-1:
                    s1[z-i]=s1[i]            
  print s1                #print pallindrome
```

I have done this with C programming logic since i come from C language.Logic seems to be right.but syntax is not working.

Comment: You don't "create an empty string array" in Python. Check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) and you will save yourself a lot of typing.

Comment: I'm unclear on the goal of the program. Do you just want to turn a string like `'hello'` into `'helloolleh'`? Or something else?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yep i intent to turn the string `hello` to `helloolleh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recent comment on another answer, I'd recommend creating a `list` and iterating through it:

```
>>> s = 'abcdcaa'
>>> l = list(s)
>>> for idx,val in enumerate(l):
...     if val != l[-idx - 1]:
...         l[-idx - 1] = val
...
>>> result = ''.join(l)
>>> print(result)
abcdcba
```

Translating a C algorithm line by line into Python code is a recipe for confusion. Design your algorithm with the target language in mind.

Comment: Why create a list? You can simply iterate over a string since it's also a sequence.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Because I wanted to mutate it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks.This is new. Thanks for such an elaborate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't code like this in Python, but to answer your question here is how you can have a certain length empty array which you can manipulate.

```
# Make 20 length array of chars
import array
s = array.array('c', " "*20)

# Set some chars
s[10] = "A"

# Show it
print "".join(s)
```